# Writing javascript function in a better way

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function returnsSomething(data1, data2) {
    let error = null;
    let something = {
      varA = data1 ? data1 : error += 'varA';
      varB = data2 ? data2 : error += 'varB';
   }
   return {
     status: error ? false : true;
     returnedData: error ? error += 'not available' : something  
  }
}
```

```
function callsThePreviousFunction() {
   let data1 = {
      a: something1,
      b: something2
   }
   let data2 = {
      a: something3,
      b: something4
   }
   let storeData = returnsSomething(data1, data2)
   if(storeData.status){
      return storeData.returnedData;
   }else{
      return false
   }
}
```

I believe the function returnsSomething can be written in a better way to return the data and return the stored errors based on the conditions. Any help will be highly appreciated. THANK YOU

Comment: For question about improvement of working code, you should post in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: FYI, `null + string = nullstring`

Comment: You should initialize `error` to an empty string, not `null`.

Comment: You can't have variable assignments inside an object literal.

Comment: @L.Faros Except the code doesn't work, it has syntax errors.

Comment: Did you mean to write `varA:` instead of `varA =`?

Comment: Is `returnsSomething` called only by `callsThePreviousFunction`?